# Global singleton use in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to centralize my actions in models defined as follow:

```
class Foobar {
    doit() {
        console.log('I am doing it');
    }
}

let foobar = new Foobar()

const app = new Vue({
   store, 
   router, 
   foobar,
   ...
})
```

Later on, in a subcomponent, I would like to trigger an action on my model and I would like to do:

```
<template>
   <b-button @click="doit">Do It</b-button>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    methods: {
        doit() {
           this.$foobar.doit(); // <----
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

It seems `$foobar` is not accessible down there.

What is the proper way in Vue to centralize actions in an external singleton?

Comment: Adding it to Vue's prototype might work, like Vue.prototype.$foobar = new Foobar()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it this way, but I'm not sure how well data will persist.

```
Vue.prototype.$foobar = foobar;
```

It might be better to use Vuex, so it is persisted through the app.

Inside the store:

```
const state = {
 foobar: Foobar
}
const mutations = {
 initialize (state) {
   state.foobar = new Foobar();
  }
}
```

Inside main/app.js:

```
store.commit('initialize')
```